# Beginners' guide for setting up Emacs with gcc/gdb?

Tags: c, emacs, development-environment

I looked around the GNU emacs material and didn't find anything helpful.

Does anyone know of a good tutorial for setting up emacs, to basically turn it into an IDE? I'm looking for interfacing with gcc/gdb/make, etc...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like other answers mentioned, `M-x compile`, `M-x gdb` will get you going. While debugging, I'd also suggest `gdb-many-windows-mode`, which makes Emacs look a bit closer to IDE when debugging.

Besides that and to get closer to "IDE-like features", you can look at:

- CEDET  http://cedet.sourceforge.net/ for code completion and project support. Excellent tutorial at http://xtalk.msk.su/~ott/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html .
- If you don't mind using non-free software, Xrefactory (http://www.xref.sk/xrefactory/main.html) is probably the best (well, the only) refactoring tool. The C version is free, the C++ is not.

Comment: I just opened question to post link to article about Cedet ;-)

Comment: for work with gdb, you can use also gdb-ui from standard distribution

Comment: Being using emacs+gdb for 8+ years now - never knew about "gdb-many-windows-mode"!!!  It's fantastic!

Answer (score 7):

Yuval, you're probably being misled by looking for something about IDEs.  All that stuff is automagically built into EMACS except for the CScope-like searching stuff.

- `M-x compile` runs *make* by default, although I reset it to run Ant in java mode.
- `M-x gdb` runs gdb
- `` C-x ` `` (Ctrl-X backquote) goes to the next compile error

and so on.

Go dig about in the [EMACS Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/).  Lots of good stuff.  The [Programming Category](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en?CategoryProgramming) is where you should look.

Answer (score 2):

[Good Article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5765)

Look at CScope too... you just have to add two lines to your .emacs to be able to navigate through definitions and references

Answer (score 1):

Even though not directly related to C/C++ i find that using a good color scheme is important. Try:

```
M-x color-theme-select
```

and you can browse around a lot of different setups if you do not want to create your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with version control system, you can find useful information in another [my article](http://xtalk.msk.su/~ott/en/writings/emacs-vcs/index.html) about work with version control systems from emacs